# How to Convert a parseFloat string number to a floating point with 2 decimal places

Tags: decimal, cart, parsefloat

In the following question/answer:

[Configure Cart Price Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963896/configure-cart-price-update)

The response gives an example that provides a working method - however, I had to change it to allow for floating point math.

The problem now is that I cannot convert the answer to 2 decimal places.  The answer is sometimes given with 15! decimal places.

Here is my modified java code from the original - how do I get it to output to 2 decimals?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var basePrice = 39.95;
    $("#baseCost").text(basePrice);
    $("#sumTotal").text(basePrice);
});

function calculateTotals(){
    var basePrice = parseFloat($("#baseCost").text(), 10);
    var upgradePrice = 0.00;
    $("#options select").each(function(){
        var optionVal = $(this).val();
        upgradePrice += parseFloat(optionVal.substr(optionVal.indexOf("_") + 1, optionVal.length - 1), 10);
    });
    $("#upgradeCost").text(upgradePrice);   
    $("#sumTotal").text(basePrice + upgradePrice);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't confuse java and javascript.

Comment: Sorry - my javascript knowledge is quite limited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every number variable has a method called toFixed.

```
var sumTotal = basePrice + upgradePrice;
$("#sumTotal").text(sumTotal.toFixed(2));
```

Edit: Changed answer to something more specific.

Comment: I tried using .toFixed(2) just about every possible place I could in the above code example.  None worked. :(

Comment: Which number needs the decimal places rounded off? That one number needs toFixed(2).

Comment: I'm trying to round off sumTotal - which is not a variable as far as I can tell. I've tried adding .toFixed(2) to it - in fact - I've tried adding .toFixed(2) to just about every spot I could think of.  The actual page that has the problem is here.  Add trigger stops to see the problem. http://cinchgaming.com/custom.php?upgrade=1

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much!!  Greg - You are a god among men.  Never let anyone tell you different.